# ReferenceError: EXIF is not defined do ng2-img-max?

Tags: angular

Eu instalei o ng2-img-max com o objetivo de redimensionar imagens. Eu quero que cada imagem enviada seja redimensionada para uma largura e comprimento pré-definidos. Eu vejo que a maioria das pessoas usam ng2-img-max ao desenvolver com angular 2/4. Eu tentei usar com essa lib e depois enfrentei alguns erros um deles é esse:

`ReferenceError: EXIF is not defined`

O erro é bem claro, estou passando por problemas parecido com o do companheiro abaixo;

[EXIF reading issue #19](https://github.com/bergben/ng2-img-max/issues/19)

Eu excluir a pasta node_modules e o arquivo **package-lock.json** e mudei a versão no arquivo **package.json** para `"ng2-img-max": "2.1.9"`, porém não tive sucesso, depois tentei a mesma coisa com a versão `"ng2-img-max": "2.1.15",` mas ainda não tive sucesso, e depois tentei incluir esse script no arquivo **app.component.html**, mas ainda não tive sucesso.

Esse tipo de problema acontece quando vou carregar a imagem.

Alguém já passou por esse problema que possa me ajudar?

Esse é meu [REPOSITÓRIO](https://github.com/wladyband/angular-sistema-vendas/tree/master/src/app/admin/edit-restaurant)

Modulos que estão instalados;

```
{
  "name": "meat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0",
    "admin-lte": "2.3.11",
    "blueimp-canvas-to-blob": "^3.14.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "ng2-img-max": "2.1.15",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "5.1.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "7.0.5",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "2.1.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.2.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

Essa é a mensagem de erro;

```
core.es5.js:1085 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: EXIF is not defined
ReferenceError: EXIF is not defined
    at img-exif.service.js:9
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:776)
    at ImgExifService.webpackJsonp.../../../../ng2-pica/dist/src/img-exif.service.js.ImgExifService.getOrientedImage (img-exif.service.js:7)
    at Image.img.onload (img-maxpx-size.service.js:24)
    at Image.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onload] (zone.js:1393)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4136)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:397)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
    at Image.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)
    at img-exif.service.js:9
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:776)
    at ImgExifService.webpackJsonp.../../../../ng2-pica/dist/src/img-exif.service.js.ImgExifService.getOrientedImage (img-exif.service.js:7)
    at Image.img.onload (img-maxpx-size.service.js:24)
    at Image.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onload] (zone.js:1393)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4136)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:397)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
    at Image.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:683) [angular]
    at :4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6444:17 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4136) [angular]
```

O aquivo que está com erro está na pasta node_modules no caminho

```
_ node_modeles
       _ ng2-img-max
              _ dist
                  _src
                    _img-exif.service.js
```

e dentro desse arquivo.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'exif-js/exif';
var ImgExifService = (function () {
    function ImgExifService() {
    }
    ImgExifService.prototype.getOrientedImage = function (image) {
        var result = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var img;
            if (!EXIF) {
                EXIF = {};
                EXIF.getData = function (img, callback) {
                    callback.call(image);
                    return true;
                };
                EXIF.getTag = function () { return false; };
            }
            EXIF.getData(image, function () {
                var orientation = EXIF.getTag(image, "Orientation");
                if (orientation != 1) {
                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"), ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"), cw = image.width, ch = image.height, cx = 0, cy = 0, deg = 0;
                    switch (orientation) {
                        case 3:
                        case 4:
                            cx = -image.width;
                            cy = -image.height;
                            deg = 180;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                        case 6:
                            cw = image.height;
                            ch = image.width;
                            cy = -image.height;
                            deg = 90;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                        case 8:
                            cw = image.height;
                            ch = image.width;
                            cx = -image.width;
                            deg = 270;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    canvas.width = cw;
                    canvas.height = ch;
                    if ([2, 4, 5, 7].indexOf(orientation) > -1) {
                        //flip image
                        ctx.translate(cw, 0);
                        ctx.scale(-1, 1);
                    }
                    ctx.rotate(deg * Math.PI / 180);
                    ctx.drawImage(image, cx, cy);
                    img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.width = cw;
                    img.height = ch;
                    img.addEventListener('load', function () {
                        resolve(img);
                    });
                    img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                }
                else {
                    resolve(image);
                }
            });
        });
        return result;
    };
    ImgExifService.decorators = [
        { type: Injectable },
    ];
    /** @nocollapse */
    ImgExifService.ctorParameters = function () { return []; };
    return ImgExifService;
}());
export { ImgExifService };
//# sourceMappingURL=img-exif.service.js.map
```

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro você escreveu `EXIF`, será que o certo não é `Exif`, afinal de contas JavaScript (TypeScript é convertido nisto) é case-sensitive.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade esse erro está vindo de um arquivo que está na pasta `node_modeles`, então é um arquivo criado pela própria lib, eu estou seguindo esse tutorial  https://alligator.io/angular/resizing-images-in-browser-ng2-img-max/  então não existe possibilidade de eu ter escrito esse código porque ele é autogerado pela propria lib, e também não me atrevo a modificar o arquivo que foi auto gerado pela lib.

Comment: E no packages.json quais modulos estão informados e instalados?

Comment: por favor veja novamente minha postagem, acabei de atualizar.

Comment: Tem como por a mensagem completa, incluindo origem?

Comment: eu não entendi a pergunta, mas se quiser ter acesso ao meu projeto, eu atualizei a minha postagem e coloquei lá o link do meu repositório, mas vou colocar aqui também <<<< https://github.com/wladyband/angular-sistema-vendas/tree/master/src/app/admin/edit-restaurant >>>>>

Comment: Abra o console do navegador com F12, aperta o F5 na tua tela da aplicação, então olha a tela do console, copia o erro completo e cola aqui. Desculpe caro @wladyband, mas eu não vou baixar um sistema inteiro para testar o problema, tem coisa que dá para você mesmo adiantar para nós se você olhar no log ou depurar com calma. Então, desta forma poderemos ir direto para o problema e te ajudar encontrando a solução. Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: eu coloquei a mensagem de erro completo na atualização da postagem e coloquei também o caminho do arquivo que está com erro e o código do arquivo que está com erro., dar uma olhada lá por favor.

Comment: Pode ser um bug, tenta atualizar pra versão `2.1.17` (versão atual). Na pasta node_modules dá uma olhada se existe o módulo `exif-js`.

Comment: acabei de atualizar e continuar com o mesmo erro, e o módulo `exif-js` se encontra no projeto.

Comment: Vou criar um projeto simples aqui e te aviso se o ocorre o mesmo erro.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento muito obrigado, se você tiver sucesso no seu projeto, gostaria que pudesse me fornecer seu projeto se não for incomodo.